# Github Desktop and LFS failed to fetch some objects from github.com/.../git/info/lfs

Tags: github, git-lfs, github-desktop

Here is the story, we have GitHub working and are using GitDesktop 1.0.10.
We are also using Git LFS 2.3.0 from https://github.com/blog/2432-git-lfs-2-3-0-released ... two devs are able to clone and push repo without issue, one has issues as follows:

```
WARNING: 'git lfs clone' is deprecated and will not be updated
          with new flags from 'git clone'
'git clone' has been updated in upstream Git to have comparable
speeds to 'git lfs clone'.
'git clone' has been updated in upstream Git to have comparable
speeds to 'git lfs clone'.
Cloning into 'C:\Git\SomeRepo'...
remote: Counting objects: 28847, done.        
remote: Compressing objects:   0% (1/331)           
remote: Compressing objects:   1% (4/331)           
remote: Compressing objects:   2% (7/331)           
...
remote: Compressing objects:  98% (325/331)           
remote: Compressing objects:  99% (328/331)           
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (331/331)           
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (331/331), done.        
Receiving objects:   0% (1/28847)   
Receiving objects:   1% (289/28847)   
Receiving objects:   2% (577/28847)   
Receiving objects:   3% (866/28847)   
...
Receiving objects:  96% (27694/28847), 974.57 MiB | 21.10 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  97% (27982/28847), 974.57 MiB | 21.10 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  98% (28271/28847), 974.57 MiB | 21.10 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  99% (28559/28847), 974.57 MiB | 21.10 MiB/s   
remote: Total 28847 (delta 547), reused 598 (delta 424), pack-reused 28092        
Receiving objects: 100% (28847/28847), 974.57 MiB | 21.10 MiB/s   
Receiving objects: 100% (28847/28847), 979.90 MiB | 20.95 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas:   0% (0/16327)   
Resolving deltas:   1% (306/16327)   
Resolving deltas:   2% (343/16327)   
Resolving deltas:   5% (822/16327)   
Resolving deltas:   7% (1162/16327)   
...
Resolving deltas:  98% (16033/16327)   
Resolving deltas:  99% (16175/16327)   
Resolving deltas: 100% (16327/16327)   
Resolving deltas: 100% (16327/16327), done.
batch response: Git credentials for 
https://github.com/SomeOrg/SomeProject.git not found:
exit status 1
batch response: Git credentials for 
https://github.com/SomeOrg/SomeProject.git not found:
exit status 1
batch response: Git credentials for 
https://github.com/SomeOrg/SomeProject.git not found:
exit status 1
batch response: Git credentials for 
https://github.com/SomeOrg/SomeProject.git not found:
exit status 1
batch response: Git credentials for 
https://github.com/SomeOrg/SomeProject.git not found:
exit status 1
batch response: Git credentials for 
https://github.com/SomeOrg/SomeProject.git not found:
exit status 1
batch response: Git credentials for 
https://github.com/SomeOrg/SomeProject.git not found:
exit status 1
batch response: Git credentials for 
https://github.com/SomeOrg/SomeProject.git not found:
exit status 1
batch response: Git credentials for 
https://github.com/SomeOrg/SomeProject.git not found:
exit status 1
error: failed to fetch some objects from 'https://github.com/SomeOrg/SomeProject.git/info/lfs'
```

I have tried:

- Logging in with working credentials on non-working machine
- Uninstalling and reinstalling Github Desktop
- Deleting files forcing the reinstall of Github Desktop to ask for settings again
- Disabled Firewall

Any help here would be very much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: @ThomasSmyth I just did.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug described in [git-lfs/git-lfs issue 2349](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/2349#issuecomment-315789602) and [Git for Windows issue 1192](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1192#issuecomment-321100378)

> > It could be a bug in the way Git for Windows calls `git-lfs.exe`: if there is no console to use, there won't be a way to communicate with the user.
> >     But then, maybe it does work with winpty as I suggested earlier (even if the OP indicated that it fails), that's why I want an MCVE.
>
> @dscho I think that this is likely. In my testing, I was unable to get LFS to see a pty/tty when invoked by Git for Windows. I have set up a test repository that I have reproduced the bug with: https://github.com/ttaylorr/lfs-gfw-bug

Still, try and install the latest [Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/releases).
And/or try the same clone from command-line, after installing the [very latest Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) (the [2.15.1.2](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.15.1.windows.2) one).

The [OP OverCodingUnderSleeping](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2358361/overcodingundersleeping) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47764272/github-desktop-and-lfs-failed-to-fetch-some-objects-from-github-com-git-info/47766213#comment82527305_47766213):

> Oddly enough, seems like switching over to SourceTree from GitHub For Desktop solved it....

That means SourceTree either use the "System" Git or an embedded one, which might not exhibit the same bug: check the settings.

Comment: Thanks for taking a stab at this @VonC - unfortunately, the latest GCM for Windows solution did not work nor did the command-line solution.  Pulling out graying hair over this!

Comment: Oddly enough, seems like switching over to SourceTree from GitHub For Desktop solved it....

Comment: @OverCodingUnderSleeping Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.